# Windows 10 IoT Core, Pi 3 Config.txt

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, config.txt

Where should I place my `config.txt` for my **Windows 10 IoT Core Raspberry Pi 3** setup? I was reading [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md), but didn't know for sure if I am simply supposed to place it in the root of the `SD card` or not?

Answer (score 2):

The last time I checked, it was in `C:\EFIESP`

Full path: `C:\EFIESP\config.txt`